# Image optimization to load webpage faster

Tags: php, apache

I have checked several thread in stackoverflow about this. I have followed several content over the net to compress the images. I have checked-

```
mod_deflate
mod_headers
mod_expires
```

for my Apache server. After two days searching I am posting here about this issue. I have tried headers, expires to write in `.htaccess` file. Nothing is working. No changes are showing in `Google Page Speed Insights`. I also have tried `W3 Total Cache`, `WP Super Cache`, `Force GZip in WP`. I need to optimize images.  What can I do? Please, suggest me.

Total Platform of my website is as follows-

1. cPanel
2. Apache Server
3. WordPress
4. MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Your question is borderline opinion-based, but... One thing you could try is [domain sharding](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/09/05/domain-sharding-revisited/). The idea is you create extra DNS records.

Say you have `mydomain.com`. Create `img1.mydomain.com`, `img2.mydomain.com`, `img3.mydomain.com`. Now when you build your pages as you create the `src` attribute for your `img` tags you loop across these domains.

The idea is this tricks browsers into spawning more threads to load the images. Your mileage may vary.

Another thing you may consider would be a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), but it's pretty hard to suggest the best course of action here without more information.